# Getting the exact time and date for my log track

Tags: java

Good day Lovely people

Please help a brother out.  Well I'm a master in visual basic but in java let me rather not say.

In VB here are my methods:

1. System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
2. System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "/" + System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "/" + System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()

The first method will return the exact time e.g = 12:08:36 AM

And the second method will return the exact date e.g = 2012/09/26

I want to get the very same results but using java.How do i go about doing that.

Oooh Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET, `DateTime.Now` gives you the *local* date and time, in your local time zone.

If you use `new Date()` or the like in Java, it will give you a value which has no awareness of time zones. To take time zones into account, you should either create a `Calendar` which has the right time zone, or if you want to create an appropriate string you should use `SimpleDateFormat` - again, set to the right time zone before formatting. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(...); // Whichever time zone you want
String text = format.format(new Date()); // "now"
```

Also note that [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) is a much better Java API for date/time than the built-in `Calendar` and `Date` classes.

Finally, your second piece of sample code in .NET is buggy - you should only evaluate `DateTime.Now` *once*; ideally just passing in a format string e.g. `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`. Even if you want to convert each bit to a string separately, however, you fetch the value once to a local variable and then reuse it. Otherwise, if you execute that code around midnight, the date can change - so for example, if you executed it *just before* the start of 2013, you could end up with a string of "2012/12/1" or "2012/1/1" neither of which would be correct.

Comment: Dear Mr Jon Skeet.Thank you very much for your help and advice i will most certainlly look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class to format date and `new java.util.Date()` will create an instance system date default.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date)); //2012/09/26
System.out.println(dateFormat1.format(new Date)); //12:08:36 AM
```

Comment: Thank you very,very,very much.you have been a great help.Did i mention thank you in my comment.ooh well If i didn't thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the object representing the current date, you can use just `new Date()`, to format it, use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).